# CSS background-size broken on mobile

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm building a site with a header element that has a fixed, full-screen background image. It works exactly as intended, except on mobile devices. Both Safari and Chrome on my iphone/ipad are not displaying it correctly--it seems to be scaling to dimensions much larger than the header element.

Here's the full site: http://www.loganmerriam.com/

And the css concerned:

```
header {
  background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
  -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
  -o-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Even when I use media queries to load a much smaller background it still only shows a tiny, zoomed section of the image.

Also can anyone direct me to a good way to inspect CSS on idevices?

Comment: I'm using http://ami.responsivedesign.is/ to look at your site, and it looks okay...

Comment: It's not the dimensions that are causing the problem it's the device. I can scale a desktop browser down and the background will work just fine, it's the touch browsers that have a problem.

Comment: I think it's related to the fixed positioning.

Comment: Are you on an iPhone/iPad? I've had similar issues using background-size:cover; on them as well. I've avoided the situation, by not using this on mobile devices. There is probably documentation somewhere about it, but I haven't come across any.

Comment: Just to comment as well on this... I had the same problem on my Galaxy s3 and getting rid of the fixed part in the background rule fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it'll be of much help, but http://screenqueri.es/index.php might do.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your styles are getting overwritten. Remove the `background-size: cover;`

```
header {
  background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
  -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
  -o-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  -webkit-background-size: cover; // remove this
  -moz-background-size: cover;  // remove this
  -o-background-size: cover;  // remove this
  background-size: cover;  // remove this
}
```

Comment: Tried that earlier, no dice. I want them to be overwritten by **cover** anyway, it's the ideal solution when it's supported.